# NTAccount.Translate() The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed

Tags: c#, .net, windows, active-directory, ldap

I have a desktop app (C# .NET, Windows 10/11) which attempts to retrieve information from the Active Directory. A call to NTAccount account to retrieve the identity of the machine and get the Security Identifier of the machine from Active Directory fails. The logic is like this:

```
        NTAccount account = new NTAccount(domainName, machineName + "$");

        SecurityIdentifier sid = (SecurityIdentifier)account.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
```

The error is:

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (1789): The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.
at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.TranslateToSids(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Boolean& someFailed)
at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean& someFailed)
at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess)
at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(Type targetType)
...

The machine is domain joined.

Now this piece of code works perfectly for workstation computers that are directly connected to the corporate network, but it fails for remote machines that connect to the corporate network via a VPN from outside to establish connectivity.

The particular VPN solution to establish connectivity is ZScaler.

Does anybody have any idea on how to debug it further? Have been analyzing logs from the Zscaler VPN but it does not provide any answer.

Does it make sense to use any low-level debugging tools to move forward with it?

Comment: How many AD DCs do you have? Which DC is the machine talking to when it's connected via the VPN? Does it _have_ network access to any DC through the VPN? (Are the machines permanently VPN-only, or do they roam between local and VPN connectivity? If they're VPN-only, are their AD computer accounts still active?)

Comment: The machine needs line-of-sight to the DC for this to work. So the VPN needs to be connected already, and needs to allow connectivity to the DC server.

Comment: Yes, this machine is permanently remote VPN only. Need to check if their AD computer accounts are still active. There are a few Domain Controllers. How would I check which particular Domain Controller the machine is talking to when connected via VPN? Is there any command / PowerShell cmdlet to check that?

In general I think there is a connectivity to the Active Directory, the computer accounts in Active Directory might be a good thing to debug.

Thank you very much.

Comment: As an update: there is a connectivity to the domain controller but the VPN channel does not allow ping connectivity (pings are being dropped on purpose). Could that be a problem and the reason for this issue?

The Active Directory account for the computer is active, I have forced password reset and tested the secure channel with PowerShell command "Test-ComputerSecureChannel". Also resynced the computer time with the Active Directory Domain Controller with commands like "w32tm /query /source" - it tells me it resynced time with the Domain Controller. Any ideas how to debug it further?